# pjsip ios : Bluetooth not working

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avaudiosession, pjsip

I'm building a sample voip app in iOS using pjsip version 2.3 (stable). Everything works fine except that bluetooth headset does not work with app.

I'm enabling bluetooth from AVAudioSession by

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];
```

I enable the AVAudioSession instance before making a call.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];
```

I disable the AVAudioSession instance after the call ends.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setActive:NO error:nil];
```

I also followed the instructions given here

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#UnabletosupportBluetoothinput):

But bluetooth does not seem to work at all.

I'm pretty sure this is something to do with pjsip because I created a simple iOS app that could record and play sound that uses AVAudioSession the same way as mentioned above and bluetooth works totally fine.

Device being used : iPhone 5s iOS 8.4

Kindly provide me inputs to configure pjsip so that I can enable bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fix by PJSIP fixed the bluetooth problem: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/changeset/5142

It seems to be working for me.

Comment: applied above solution but not working. have you other suggestion for Bluetooth call using pjsip ios?